# How do I stop Exchange 2019 Global Address List (GAL) showing up on Samsung Android 12 smartphone?

Tags: android, exchange-server, samsung-galaxy, gal

I have set up an Exchange account (2019 on-premises) on a Samsung S10e Android 12 smartphone and only let it sync the calendar, not mails or contacts. Now when the user opens the contacts app it also lists all entries from the global address list (GAL) of the Exchange 2019 server. How can I hide the GAL on the smartphone? I have not found an option that deals with the visibility of the GAL... (On my Pixel 6 Pro smartphone the GAL does not appear... only on this Galaxy S10e.)

Side question: I generally don't want the Exchange users to see the GAL, so when I connect a Windows Outlook client I always manually exclude the GAL from the address book. Is there a way I can hide the GAL from the beginning? Like tell Exchange to make the GAL unavailable to the normal users? However, I as an admin want to see the GAL in my personal Outlook environment, so just setting "don't display in GAL" for every user does not help. (Also, hiding accounts from the GAL sometimes causes other negative side effects, so I'd rather not hide entries from the GAL, but rather limit the GAL visibility as such.)